# Slide from the side effect

Tags: jquery, iframe

Here is a site with an effect I'm trying to figure out: http://www.scyphus.co.uk

I wonder how they made the iframe come out from the right side? Particularly, what they used for the nice slide effect? Thx for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple jQuery animation:

CSS:

```
#myContainer {
    position : absolute;
    left     : 2000px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myContainer').animate({
    left : '100px'
}, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/Ler4d/

I added some jQueryUI easing, but you can choose the one that's most appropriate for your application. For easing types, check out the [jQueryUI easing demo](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html).

Comment: Thx I used hide instead of shoving it to the left. Just starting with coding.